# How can I figure out why biber stopped working all of a sudden?

Tags: biblatex, biber

**edit on 2013-08-28** It just happened again. What are the steps I can take to possibly figure out what went wrong?

I have no idea what's going on.

Just 30 minutes ago everything was fine and 5 minutes ago it stopped working.

Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass[
12pt,
a4paper,
english,
]
{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[
language=auto,
style=authoryear,
backend=biber,
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\begin{filecontents*}{lit.bib}
@Book{augustine,
  hyphenation     = {american},
  author      = {Augustine, Robert L.},
  title       = {Heterogeneous catalysis for the synthetic chemist},
  shorttitle      = {Heterogeneous catalysis},
  publisher   = {Marcel Dekker},
  location    = {New York},
  date        = {1995},
    edition={1},
  annotation      = {A plain \texttt{book} entry}
}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
\newunit
\printlist{publisher}%
\newunit
\printlist{location}%
\newunit}

\addbibresource{lit.bib}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Some words for the \verb+book+.\footcite[See][p. 19]{augustine}
\end{itemize}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This is the code of the error (in German, unfortunately):

```
Problemsignatur:
  Problemereignisname:  APPCRASH
  Anwendungsname:   biber.exe
  Anwendungsversion:    0.0.0.0
  Anwendungszeitstempel:    51194dbe
  Fehlermodulname:  perl516.dll
  Fehlermodulversion:   0.0.0.0
  Fehlermodulzeitstempel:   5093098b
  Ausnahmecode: c0000005
  Ausnahmeoffset:   00001427
  Betriebsystemversion: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Gebietsschema-ID: 1031
  Zusatzinformation 1:  4c0d
  Zusatzinformation 2:  4c0d4d78887f76d971d5d00f1f20a433
  Zusatzinformation 3:  4c0d
  Zusatzinformation 4:  4c0d4d78887f76d971d5d00f1f20a433

Lesen Sie unsere Datenschutzbestimmungen online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0407

Wenn die Onlinedatenschutzbestimmungen nicht verfügbar sind, lesen Sie unsere Datenschutzbestimmungen offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\de-DE\erofflps.txt
```

My system:

- Win 7 64 bit
- TXC 2 Beta 2 64 bit

The output profile in TXC:

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with Windows or TeXnic Centre, but that 'error message' is rather uninformative.  What error(s) do you get if you run `biber` from a command terminal or DOS prompt (actually, I'm not sure of the exact term)?

Comment: Your edit doesn't add anything to your question.  Kurt was able to solve your problem by noticing an extra `}`.  Since you are having this problem again, are there again any extra brackets of any kind?

Comment: Does restarting the computer fix the problem? Sometimes Windows can be emotional that way.

Comment: @Werner Yes, restarting helped. But why? It leaves the user rather helpless and just looks like the obligatory question from tech support: "did rebooting help?" Dustin, I checked the file. No extra brackets. One thing though was odd insofar that Notepad++ does not recognize the brackets the url in `url={http://www.ctan.org}` but in TXC it works just fine.